# How to modify (add files or directories) to the qemu-img created raw disk file?

Tags: filesystems, qemu, mount

How to add files or directories to the `qemu-img` created raw disk file. For example. I use `qemu-img create -f raw disk.raw 1G` to generate a `disk.raw` file. I want to copy some `/bin`, `/usr` directories to the `disk.raw` file.

I have tried the following commands. With the reference to [here](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=c02814204&docLocale=en_US).

```
qemu-img create -f raw disk.raw 1G
mkdir /image
losetup /dev/loop0 disk.raw
fdisk /dev/loop0
    > n
    > p
    > ENTER
    > ENTER
    > ENTER
    > a
    > w
kpartx -a /dev/loop0
mount /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /image
```

However, the last commands output the following error messages: `mount: /image: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/loop0p1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/loop0p1`
2. `mount /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /image`